# Sublime Text 2 - "reopen with encoding" key binding

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way to define a key binding to reopen current file with another specific encoding? Say, `ctrl + alt + w` to reopen current file with Windows-1251 ?

Sublime lacks success at detecting this encoding, and using `File - Reopen with encoding ..` just takes too much time when I work with lots of files in Windows-1251.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add this to your `Preferences` > `Key Bindings - User` file.

```
 {
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+w"],
    "command": "reopen", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)" }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: worked like a charm for me as well, sublime text 3. Thx a lot! You saved my day.